# How can I update css/HTML in a post request?

Tags: css, node.js, express, post

I am working on a page that has several sections. One of them is a form, which sends a POST request. After the form is successfully sent, I would like to update a CSS style on another element to make it visible.

Since the submit event is happening server-side (using node.js), how can I have this file communicate with the CSS/HTML? I don't want to send a whole new page, just slightly update the one that's already displayed.

```
app.post("/section-2", function(req, res) { 
  console.log(req.body);
  authorizeAndExecute(findOpenDataRow);

  res.send("<style>.section-2-next{visibility:visible}</style>")
});
```

The example above shows something I've tried, but it is just clearing the whole page. I also tried jQuery, but the server is obviously not connected to the HTML in the way a regular js file is.

EDIT: Here is some of the HTML that involves the form, and the element that I'd like to update the style of.

```
<form action="/section-2" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg section-2-submit">Submit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-success section-2-next" type="button" name="button">Continue</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Try sending ajax request and update the particular element on success, otherwise with this scenario your whole page will be refreshed.

Comment: Please include your client side code where you are making the POST request.

Comment: @CalIrvine, just updated it to include some of the HTML. Is that enough, or what else would you expect to see?

Comment: @Chuck do you have any client side javascript handling the submit, or are you using that form action? That will always cause a redirect. You want javascript to send the request to your backend using AJAX if you don't want your page to change. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript

Comment: @CalIrvine, I am just using the form action. I will look into the javascript. Thanks.

Comment: @Chuck also look into the fetch api and axios as they can make this kind of thing easier to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax on the client side in order to apply your style when the POST is done.
If you use jQuery, the syntax would be :

```
$('.my-form').submit((e) => { // Will be triggered when submit input is clicked
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent page redirection
  $.post('/section-2', { param1: value1, ... }) // do POST with query parameters
  .done((res) => { // on response from POST
    $('.section-2-next').css('visibility', 'visible'); // Update your style
  })
})
```

Comment: You shouldn't assume jQuery, while it used to be the norm, it is far from it these days. A lot of people learning JavaScript these days don't bother with it. That said, the answer is not wrong. What @Chuck decides to do would depend on his project.

Comment: What are the query parameters that I would need to include in the POST?

Comment: It depends on what you need to do server side when the POST is received. If nothing, then you may not need any parameters.